# Getting First qualified order date for each account and show how many of them by Month

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm a SQL guy starting in a PBI position and I've been facing some difficulties so far:

First, I have only access to a Power BI Data set, and it does not allow Direct Query, so I build my own over it. But even this new DS with DirectQuery enabled can be used as a data source in the Power Query Editor so I'm confined on that little coding window that shows up when you want to create a column, table or measure.

Despite this, I've managed to work my way through all the requests I have got so far, but one little visual is driving me crazy:

I need a visual showing how many accounts performed their first qualified purchase by month, A qualified purchase should:

Showing "PAID" in 'Orders'[Status]
Having no LineItems with SKU from {"A","B","C"} in 'OrderLines'

I tried to approach this by creating a table showing the first Qualified Order date for each account, my code looks as follows:

```
QualifiedFirstOrders = 
FILTER(
    SUMMARIZE(
        'Orders',
        'Orders'[OrderID],
        'Orders'[AccountId],
        'Orders'[Status],
        'Orders'[OrderDate],
        'OrderLines'[SKU]
    ),
    'Orders'[Status] = "PAID" &&
    NOT (
        'Orders'[OrderID] IN
        (
            SELECTCOLUMNS (
                FILTER (
                    'OrderLines',
                    'OrderLines'[OrderID] = 'Orders'[OrderID] &&
                    'OrderLines'[SKU] IN {"A","B","C"}
                ),
                "OrderID", 'OrderLines'[OrderID]
            )
        )
    ) &&
    CALCULATE(
        COUNTROWS('Orders'),
        FILTER(
            ALL('Orders'),
            'Orders'[OrderID] <> EARLIER('Orders'[OrderID]) &&
            'Orders'[OrderDate] < EARLIER('Orders'[OrderDate]) &&
            'Orders'[Status] = "PAID" &&
            NOT (
                'Orders'[OrderID] IN
                (
                    SELECTCOLUMNS (
                        FILTER (
                            'OrderLines',
                            'OrderLines'[OrderID] = 'Orders'[OrderID] &&
                            'OrderLines'[SKU] IN {"A","B","C"}
                        ),
                        "OrderID", 'OrderLines'[OrderID]
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ) = 0
)
```

With this, the minimum I need is something similar to the result of this SQL query (Having orderID is a plus):

```
SELECT AccountID, MIN(OrderDate) from Accounts a LEFT JOIN Orders o ON a.accountID = a.AccountID and o.Status = 'PAID' and o.OrderID not in (Select distinct(OrderID) from OrderLines where SKU in ('A','B','C')) group by AccountID
```

Current Status: This table code fails, showing an error saying it surpasses the table row limit, which is not right as DB has around 300K distinct orders and just a few should be first qualified order.